# Нужно конвертировать base64 код в PNG изображение с помощью PHP

Tags: pdf, canvas, base64, html5, png

Добрый вечер всем пользователям ХэшКод. Возникла такая задача - я экспортирую из HTML5 элемента Canvas изображение, оно имеет вид:
`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfQAAAH0CAYAAADL1t+KAAASFUlEQVR4nO...`

Затем мне нужно передать этот base64 код PNG изображения на сервер, где стоит PHP (это не вызывает никаких проблем). Проблема состоит в том, чтобы на сервере конвертировать base64 код в PNG изображение, сохранить его на сервере, а затем вставить его (PNG изображение) в PDF и сохранить готовый PDF файл на сервере (с этим тоже никаких трудностей). А вот с конвертацией base64 кода в изображение - БЕДА. Помогите кто чем может - советом, алгоритмом, полезными ссылками. Заранее благодарен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так существует же **base64_decode**

```
$img= 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfQAAAH0CAYAAADL1t+KAAASFUlEQVR4nO...';
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo base64_decode($img);
```

**UPD:**

> ...сохранить его на сервере,...

Действительно забыл упомянуть о том, как сохранить его на сервере.
Думается через fopen.

```
$img= base64_decode('iVBORw0KGgoAAAA...');
$fpng = fopen("img.png", "w");
fwrite($fpng,$img);
fclose($fpng);
```

Всё, картинку сохранили можно ниже вставлять её куда нужно.

Comment: Сейчас попробую, спасибо!

Comment: А потом нужно полученные данные записать в файл, как бинарные, с расширением .png?

Comment: Я без понятия как Вы там её вставляете, так, что это Вы сами думайте, но выше ответил как сохранить.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку решения, еще можно сохранить файл функцией file_put_contents()

Answer (score 0):

На PHP:

```
if(!empty($_POST["image"]) {
  $enc = explode(",", $_POST["image"]);
  $enc = str_replace(" ", "+", $enc[1]);
  $ens = base64_decode($enc);
  $new_file = __DIR__."/"."myfile.png";
  file_put_contents($new_file, $ens);
}
```

На NODE.js:

```
"use strict";
const fs = require("fs");
let data = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfQAAAH0CAYAAADL1t+KAAASFUlEQVR4nO...";
fs.writeFileSync(`folder/file.png`, Buffer.from(data.replace('data:image/png;base64,', ''), "base64"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Анализ строки на наличие data:image/***;base64
сохранение фото 
вставка ссылки

```
public function replacing_base64_url($str, $temat, $l) { 
    $dir = 'img/';
    $str = str_split($str);
    $base64 = $strN= '';
    $i= $f= 0;
    foreach($str as $k => $s){
            $sn = $str[$k-2].$str[$k-1].$str[$k];
            $n = $str[$k+1].$str[$k+2].$str[$k+3].$str[$k+4];
            $sk = $str[$k-1].$str[$k].$str[$k+1];

            if($sn == 'c="' && $n != 'http'){
                $f = 1;
                $i++;
            }elseif($sk == '=" '){
                $name = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "_", $temat)).'_'.$l.'_';
                if(strpos($base64, 'jpg') !== false){
                    $typ = '.jpg';
                }elseif(strpos($base64, 'png') !== false){
                    $typ = '.png';
                }elseif(strpos($base64, 'jpeg') !== false){
                    $typ = '.jpeg';
                }elseif(strpos($base64, 'svg') !== false){
                    $typ = '.svg';
                }elseif(strpos($base64, 'webp') !== false){
                    $typ = '.webp';
                }
                $name = htmlspecialchars_decode($dir.$name.$i.$typ);
                // echo $name.'</br>' ;
                $url = 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/'.$name;
                // echo $url.'</br>';
                $strN .= $url;
                // echo $name.'</br>' ;
                $mar = 'base64,';
                $base64 = str_replace($mar, '', strstr($base64, $mar));
                $img= base64_decode($base64);
                file_put_contents($name, $img);
                $f = 0;
            }elseif($f==1){

                $base64 .= $s;

            }elseif($f==0){
                $strN .= $s;
            }
        }

    return $strN;
}
```